# How to sanitize the shared library in AOSP

Tags: address-sanitizer

My HAL is a shared library. I want to do the address sanitize for the shared library alone. I added below lines in the file(Android.mk) where we build the HAL as a shared library.

1. LOCAL_SANITIZE:=address
2. LOCAL_MODULE_RELATIVE_PATH := asan

Then I got an error like "*(SHARED_LIBRARIES android-x86_64) missing libasan.vendor (STATIC_LIBRARIES android-x86_64)*". So I added sanitize flag in all the dependent static libraries. One of the libraries has Android.bp file instead of Android.mk so I added sanitize: {address: true}, then it through an error (*module "libaudiohw_legacy" variant "android_x86_64_silvermont_static_core": depends on disabled module "libasan"*)

As per the document (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan) I read like, due to the way ASan works, a library built with ASan can only be used by an executable that's built with ASan. So I made the executable as asan by adding below two lines. Removed all other changes. 
***LOCAL_SANITIZE:=address
LOCAL_MODULE_RELATIVE_PATH := asan***
Then the executable and shared library which is under executable also put /system/lib/asan instead of /system/lib. But while booting up the bootup library will search the binary in the /system/lib which it won't find and won't boot up also.

Android version---- Oreo 8.1.0_r33

If anybody has the proper steps/documentation to sanitize the shared library, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below link for building the native libraries and binaries for address sanitization and it works fine for me.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan#sanitizing_individual_executables_with_asan

Steps:

1. Do repo sync
2. Give a clean build
3. After the build is ready do the required changes in Android make file for
   native libraries as well as for binaries.
4. Give a build again without deleting any old intermediates.